# i want to get div element code like childs with event functions in vuejs

Tags: javascript, vue.js

in my project my new requirement is we can create a page with custom buttons in one page with different screen position and optional to add and no.of same buttons to add and we can use event functions in another page like docuSign project

i would like to get element childs with event functions in vujs

Answer (score 0):

In vue you can access (idiomatically) elements using the `$refs` property. You would put on an element `ref="myEl"` and then in your code you can grab the element on some event like so:

```
this.$refs.myEl.el.<do something>
```

Comment: i am getting innetHTML without eventlisteners like <button type="button" style="height: 100%; width: 100%;"> Signin </button>

Comment: but i want like <button type="button" onClick="tet()" style="height: 100%; width: 100%;"> Signin </button>

Comment: Not really sure what you are seeing but if you are using Vue why are trying to manipulate the DOM? The recommended way is to simply put a vue directive `v-if` and render the element you want based on that, if you want to have dynamic classes. no. problem. vue supports that as well `:class="isSomething? 'style1' : 'style2'"`

Comment: actually my requirement is i can drag elements from menu plase it in required position after that i need to save this template i can share this template to any user they can do work and i want to save this template

Comment: Why not.  use a package for Drag and drop?

Comment: i am using plugin. here my problem how to save this template for future reference with element OnClick  functions.